# psql on WSL: Not listing all databases for owner postgres

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, psql, ubuntu-20.04, postgresql-13

I'm trying to setup Postgres on WSL (bash) to be able to use pg_dump (as an absolute beginner).

I've followed the steps from [here](https://computingforgeeks.com/how-to-install-postgresql-13-on-ubuntu/) twice, once after purging the entire installation.

At step 3: I used

```
sudo service postgresql status
```

as

```
systemctl status postgresql.service
```

returned

```
"System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). Can't operate.
Failed to connect to bus: Host is down"
```

After starting the service using

```
sudo service postgresql start
```

I accessed postgres using

```
sudo -u postgres psql
```

Here, the list of databases returned are

```
List of databases
   Name    |  Owner   | Encoding | Collate |  Ctype  |   Access privileges
-----------+----------+----------+---------+---------+-----------------------
 postgres  | postgres | UTF8     | C.UTF-8 | C.UTF-8 |
 template0 | postgres | UTF8     | C.UTF-8 | C.UTF-8 | =c/postgres          +
           |          |          |         |         | postgres=CTc/postgres
 template1 | postgres | UTF8     | C.UTF-8 | C.UTF-8 | =c/postgres          +
           |          |          |         |         | postgres=CTc/postgres
(3 rows)
```

While PostgreSQL shell returns me the list of **ALL** my databases.

```
List of databases
   Name    |  Owner   | Encoding |          Collate           |           Ctype            |   Access privileges
-----------+----------+----------+----------------------------+----------------------------+-----------------------
 postgres  | postgres | UTF8     | English_United States.1252 | English_United States.1252 |
 snappdev  | postgres | UTF8     | English_United States.1252 | English_United States.1252 |
 template0 | postgres | UTF8     | English_United States.1252 | English_United States.1252 | =c/postgres          +
           |          |          |                            |                            | postgres=CTc/postgres
 template1 | postgres | UTF8     | English_United States.1252 | English_United States.1252 | =c/postgres          +
           |          |          |                            |                            | postgres=CTc/postgres
(4 rows)
```

snappdev database is what I'm trying to take a dump of. However, it is not listing on WSL (ubuntu). I also tried changing permissions (chmod / chown). I have made the recommended changes on postgresql.conf and pg_hba.conf.

Also, after I do

```
sudo -u postgres
```

I'm constantly being asked for postgres password even when I'm trying to change its password. For this, I've also tried

```
psql -c "alter user postgres with password 'StrongAdminP@ssw0rd'"
```

which keeps asking me the password for the user, and

```
sudo passwd postgres
```

along with other steps recommended [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/tutorials/wsl-database).

I'm not really sure at this point what I'm missing or if taken some terribly wrong steps. Appreciate any help on this.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Just a friendly, neighborhood heads-up that questions on this site should be about *"specific coding, algorithm, or language problems."* The way this question is phrased, at least, it is about *configuration* and would likely be better suited for [Super User](https://superuser.com). I would recommend either editing it to clarify if it really is a programming question or deleting it here and reposting it on the proper site. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

use `sudo -u postgres psql` i use this when i access psql on wsl 2 on ubuntu 20.04 i hope this one helps you

Comment: Regardless of this command, the issue of DB not getting listed remains.